# How to accept user input in multi dimension list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to place user input in a multi dimension list in python. I am new at Python. Some user inputs would be

```
11001111
10001100
11000000
```

I need to place them in list

```
a[[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

What I do. And its completely useless

```
for i in range(3):
    for b in range(7):
        a[i][b] = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work too :

```
a = []
for x in range(3):
    a.append([int(let) for let in input('enter number:\n')])
```

Comment: This one Exactly Works for me: Thanks

Comment: @sagarDevkoka thanks, you should consider using solution from @Jean-francois-fabre too, with a pretty one-liner `a = [[int(x) for x in input('enter number:\n')] for _ in range(3) ]`

Comment: How can i accept string in list? I should give two lines and I Should keep each line in one index? how can I do that?

Comment: @sagarDevkoka this depends on how you want to handle the result object later, but if you need to store entire strings, this code cannot work and another input/process is required

Answer (score 3):

You can either read a line at a time and process individual characters:

```
for i in range(3):
    line = input()
    for b in range(7):
        a[i][b] = int(line[b])
```

Or you can read a character at a time:

```
sys.stdin.read(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you accept that the users types 21 digits+enter each time, what you're doing works, although it isn't the best way, looks a lot like C code.

However, it's not useless, it works provided you initialize your bidimensional array properly for instance like this:

```
a = [[0]*7 for _ in range(3)]
```

this creates 3 lists of 7 elements. You can read/write them with this exact loop you posted.

If you want to read 3 lines of single digit numbers, you could do it in only like using double list comprehension:

```
a = [[int(x) for x in input()] for _ in range(3) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
a = []
for i in range(3):
    k = raw_input()
    a.append([int(j) for j in k])

print a
```