# How to accept user input string in multi dimension list in Python?

Tags: python

Here what I want is to accept user inputs they could be

```
Hello I am Ram
I am from pokhara
I need to go home
```

And my list should be:

```
a[[Hello I am Ram],[I am from pokhara],[I need to go home]]
```

What I tied is

```
a = []
for x in range(4):
    a[i] = ([let for let in input('')])
```

as in 
[How to accept user input in multi dimension list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45769176/how-to-accept-user-input-in-multi-dimension-list-in-python)

Comment: Do you really want a list of single element lists as opposed to a list of N elements?

Comment: a list should have 3 list each internal list should accept one line and other to be go to next internal list.

Comment: the input is given with all 3 lines, or each line separately ?

Comment: There are 3 lines each separated with Enter.

Comment: @SagarDevkota errr... but what I'm asking is... doesn't `['line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3']` make more sense than `[['line 1'], ['line 2'], ['line 3']]` - there's no need to have single element lists as opposed to a list of strings is there?

Comment: @JonClements First one will be better.

Comment: To put it another way... does: `a = [input('Enter line {}'.format(n)) for n in range(1, 4)]` do what you want?

Comment: He wants: a = [[input('Enter line {}'.format(n))] for n in range(1, 4)]

Comment: @JonClements Exactly Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use python3 command to run.

```
a = []
for x in range(4):
    a.append([input('')])
print (a)
```

Length:

```
a = []
for x in range(4):
    l = input('')
    a.append(l)
    print (len(l))
```

repetittion:

```
d = {}
for n in range(1, 4):
    v = input('Enter line {}'.format(n))
    if v in d:
        d[v] = d[v] + 1
    else:
        d[v] = 1
print (d)
```

Comment: just append the input without processing is more like what is expected

Comment: as @PRMoureu says...looks like the op just wants to add the line, not a list of the individual characters...

Comment: How to count the length of the internal string?

Comment: Or you want count repetition?

Answer (score 0):

Your input seems to be:

```
>>> input_string = 'Hello I am Ram\nI am from pokhara\nI need to go home'
```

Hence you can you can use list comprehension to get your result:

```
>>> a = [[s] for s in input_string.split('\n')]
>>> print(a)
    [['Hello I am Ram'], ['I am from pokhara'], ['I need to go home']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_list = []

while(1):

    u_input = input()

    if not u_input:

        break

    input_list.append([u_input])

print input_list
```

This will accept input unless you dont give an type anything and give enter